# Power saving mode does not work properly - 22.04

Tags: power-management, 22.04

I installed newest LTS version of Ubuntu (22.04) and I have a problem with power save. I set in Gnome preferences: Power -> Power Saving -> Blank screen -> 5 minutes

1. I see black screen with mouse pointer after waiting 5minuts. The screen will not switch off (does not work power save/sleep mode).
2. The monitor goes into power save/sleep mode, when I use "lock screen". But I can't awaken it from this mode.

Thank you in advanced for you help.